# If I convert 10 V, 1 ampere to 5 V, do I get 5 V 2 ampere?

Tags: voltage, current, transformer, ampere-hour

I know the current in the circuit is the same.

And also,

Power = 10* 1 = 10 watts.

So, 
10 = 5 V * (x) ampere, 
X = 10/5, 
X = 2 ampere,

With some loss while using a voltage regulator, I will get some loss in current also ... That's not a problem. All I need is: if I reduce the voltage, do I get the same 5 V 2 ampere?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you use a linear regulator, no. You get 5 V, 1 A.

If you use a buck converter, not quite. The converter is not 100% efficient. Maybe you get 8.5 or 9 W out, so 5 V, 1.7 or 1.8 A.

Comment: A synchronous converter may get you 95% efficiency, but they often need specific MOSFET's and inductor per given PWM IC.

Comment: And that's why I gave you a +1.

Comment: Essentially you get 5V and (2 * (convertor_efficiency/100)) A.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, if you use the right type of converter, there is conservation of power between input and output. You cannot assume there will be no inefficiency, so `output power = E * input power`, where the efficiency is between 0.5 and 0.95, unless you've chosen the wrong converter for the job.

A transformer (for AC) or a buck converter (for DC) can step down voltage and increase available output current. A good efficiency to aim for is 0.8 or 0.85, and it will depend on the parts you choose. Converter chips are often flexible in what input and/or output voltages they can handle, as well as the max current. But they are targeted at a certain input and output, and they will be less efficient the further you deviate from this. Also, some chips will be made for a fixed output (e.g., always 5 V output), and others will need to be tuned based on which external components you attach. But I think all chips will need some external components added, if you plan to switch such a high current.

Don't go for "linear" converters, because they bleed off excess voltage (thus, power as well) as heat rather than converting it.